# Export data with images to Excel

Tags: asp.net, export-to-excel

I am exporting data with images to `Excel` by using the following code.

**Code**

```
protected void ExportToExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Get the data from database into datatable
    string strQuery = "select CustomerID, ContactName, City, PostalCode, display_picture" +
        " from customers";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
    DataTable dt = GetData(cmd);

    //Create a dummy GridView
    GridView GridView1 = new GridView();
    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
     "attachment;filename=DataTable.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    for (int i = 0; i  .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } ";
    Response.Write(style);
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

The `Excel` is downloading properly. But the problem is when I am filtering the data in the `Excel`. The images in the `Excel` are in `Move but don't size with cells` property. How to make the images with the property, `Move and size with cells`?

Comment: That's not Excel, that's just an HTML table with a fake content type that Excel *may* be able to import using default settings. Use a library like EPPlus to create real Excel files. It's a LOT easier

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : Thank you, I will check that. And is it possible to add images as like text with [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)

Comment: EPplus generates real Excel files, so yes, it's possible to add pictures, pivot tables, connections, etc. There are many questions in SO that show how to do this, including questions about positioning, styling etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't create an Excel file at all, it creates an HTML table and sends it with a fake content type, that of the old binary Excel format (xls). Excel isn't fooled, it detects that this is an HTML table and tries to import it using default settings. This can break for any number of reasons.

It's far easier and cheaper to create a real Excel file with a library like [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebapplicationExample). For starters, you can fill a sheet directly from a DataTable  :

```
protected void ExportToExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ///...
    DataTable dt = GetData(cmd);

    using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        //Create the worksheet
        var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Demo");
        //Load the datatable into the sheet, starting from cell A1. 
        //Print the column names on row 1
        ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);
        //That's it!

        //Write it back to the client
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=ExcelDemo.xlsx");
        Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
    }
}
```

You can add pictures with the `Drawings.AddPicture` method :

```
ExcelPicture pic = ws.Drawings.AddPicture("pic1", new FileInfo("PathToMyImage.png"));
```

The result is an `xlsx` file which is a package of compressed XML files. This means it's actually *smaller* than the HTML table or CSV files that are often generated instead of actual Excel files.

Answer (score 1):

[EasyXLS](http://www.easyxls.com) is a library that also exports xlsx and xls files with images.

```
//Create a workbook
ExcelDocument workbook = new ExcelDocument();

//Add a worksheet
ExcelWorksheet worksheet = new ExcelWorksheet("Gridview");
workbook.easy_addWorksheet(worksheet);

//Add the gridview to the worksheet
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.Tables.Add((DataTable)GridView1.DataSource);
worksheet.easy_insertDataSet(dataSet);

//Add an image
worksheet.easy_addImage("image.jpg", "A10");

//Exporting gridview with image
workbook.easy_WriteXLSXFile("DataTable.xlsx");
```

---

More about inserting images, you can find at:

http://www.easyxls.com/manual/basics/excel-image-import-export.html

If the image bytes are loaded from database, you will need to temporary save the image locally on machine.

You can also check [how to export gridview to excel](http://www.easyxls.com/manual/FAQ/export-gridview-to-excel.html) to see more about formatting the data.